# PayPal IPN _notify-validate throws Error 302 in Sandbox

Tags: paypal, sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

The second IPN response after sending **cmd=_notify-validate** to **www.sandbox.paypal.com** returns **HTTP Error 302**.

If I change the URL to **www.paypal.com**, it returns **INVALID** response. I am not sure where I am wrong.

Should I use www.paypal.com as a host to validate the IPN in sandbox? I don't think so?

I am really struggling to get this sorted. Any help please?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and it appears that sandbox has switched to ssl. I had to change my code from:

```
$fp = fsockopen ($paypalUrl, "80", $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

to:

```
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://'.$paypalUrl, "443", $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

and it worked. I found this  solution at http://www.jomres.net/jomres-forum/General-discussion/10590-PayPal-IPN----IP-Address-Expansion

Comment: Thanks periklis for your tip, it worked perfectly. Is it possible to keep the ssl protocol for production ?

Comment: I'm also trying to find a solution that will work when I run the server as localhost. Before one used to be able to just use HTTP. Do I understand it that they have removed this option now? One has to use SSL at all times?

Comment: You don't have to use ssl on your side, you just connect to paypal using ssl. In order to test this as localhost, you need a valid domain name for your machine (I used to use dyndns for this purpose, worked well, but remember to setup your adsl router to map port 80 to your pc, if you're using such a setup)

Answer (score 1):

That's not an HTTP error, that's the HTTP response code for accessing https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate

You should be looking at the contents of the page, not the HTTP response code.